# Fourier Sine Transform formula for $ \mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}} \{ \mathcal{F_{s}}(k) \mathcal{G_{s}}(k) \} $

Tags: fourier-transform

Refer to [This book](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=56c4564d5cd9e3c21f8b457e&assetKey=AS%3A330076274085892%401455707725045) for this discussion.

**NOTE**: By Fourier Sine Transform, I am **NOT** referring to complex part of complex Fourier Transform (which is $0$ for even functions), but the single sided sine transform as defined below, which can be non-zero for even functions too.

Definitions from the book:

$$\mathcal{F_{c}}\{f(x)\} = \mathcal{F_{c}}(k) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \text{f(x) cos(kx) dx}$$
$$\mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}}\{\mathcal{F_{c}}(k)\} = f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_{c}}(k) \text{cos(kx) dk}$$
$$\mathcal{F_{s}}\{f(x)\} = \mathcal{F_{s}}(k) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \text{f(x) sin(kx) dx}$$
$$\mathcal{F_{s}^{-1}}\{\mathcal{F_{s}}(k)\} = f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_{s}}(k) \text{sin(kx) dk}$$

There is a derivation on page 102 of the book for the formula below.
$$ \mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}} \{ \mathcal{F_{c}}(k) \mathcal{G_{c}}(k) \} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} f(\xi) [g(\xi+x)+g(|\xi-x|)] d\xi$$

There is a derivation on page 103 of the book for the formula below.
$$ \mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}} \{ \mathcal{F_{s}}(k) \mathcal{G_{s}}(k) \} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} f(\xi) [g(\xi+x)+g(\xi-x)] d\xi$$

**Question**: The derivations seem to be correct when I follow the steps, but somehow the formula is not proving to be correct if I take concrete examples. For example, if I take $\text{f(x) = g(x) = rect(x)}$, only the formula for $\mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}} \{ \mathcal{F_{c}}(k) \mathcal{G_{c}}(k) \}$ seems to be correct, **but not** the formula for $\mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}} \{ \mathcal{F_{s}}(k) \mathcal{G_{s}}(k) \}$. Can someone help point to the error in the latter formula (and correct it) or prove that it actually works for $\text{f(x) = g(x) = rect(x)}$. I am not worried about the scaling factors, so go with any usual choice of definition for the rect function (boxcar).

Comment: Sorry my mathjax looked fine when I was composing, but it is all screwed up now. Can someone please help? All the \\{ seem to have made new lines when they were only meant to produce {

Comment: I fixed the mathjax. Thanks for anyone who attempted to fix

Comment: Shouldn't $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$ in your last two formulas be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. You are right. I fixed them now. Any thoughts on the correctness of the formula itself? (F(s))^2 (when f =g = even) itself should be even  if F(s) is expected to be odd. So the second formula looking somewhat like the first one is okay in my mind, but the two formulas collapse to exactly the same when f=g=even. Something is not right. I can't pinpoint. The (F(c))^2 formula checks out for f=g=rect.

Comment: For

$$f(x)=g(x)=\theta (x-1)-\theta (x-2)\tag{1}$$

I get

$$\mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}} \{ \mathcal{F_{s}}(k)\, \mathcal{G_{s}}(k) \} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(\xi) \left(g(\xi+x)-\frac{1}{2}\, g(x-\xi)\right) \, d\xi\,,\quad x\ge 0\tag{2}.$$

Comment: I don't even understand the first step in the proof of the first relationship  on the top of page 102 which goes from

$$\mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}}\, \{\mathcal{F_{c}}(k)\, \mathcal{G_{c}}(k)\}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_{c}}(k)\, \mathcal{G_{c}}(k)\, \cos(x k) \, dk\tag{3}$$

to

$$\mathcal{F_{c}^{-1}}\, \{\mathcal{F_{c}}(k)\, \mathcal{G_{c}}(k)\}=\frac{2}{\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathcal{G_{c}}(k)\, \cos(x k) \, dk\ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} f(\xi)\, \cos(k \xi) \, d\xi\tag{4}$$ which I'm interpreting as the product of two integrals.

Comment: How does one justify pulling

$$\mathcal{F_{c}}(k)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} f(\xi)\, \cos(k \xi) \, d\xi\tag{5}$$

out of the initial integral over $k$ when its a function of $k$?

Comment: Even I got confused, but later realized that it is not a product, just an integral within another integral, which he does correctly in the next step by pulling that function of k back into the integral involving k

Comment: I realized the mistakes in the formulas. The formulas work when the functions are one sided. When we apply them to signals valid on the whole real axis, they need to be corrected. First of all, the basic inverse sine transform when dealing with an even function should be sgn(x) f(x) and not f(x). Then the F(s)^2 formula will get $g(x+\xi) sgn(x+\xi)$+$g(x-\xi)sgn(x-\xi)$. I really suck at mathjax, so didn't post a proper reply (my first post took me so long to compose). Note that my remarks are all for even functions defined on real axis (like my rect example)